# How do i integrate the contents of one table into another in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a site that runs on word press. I changed hosts recently so i had to do a database restore into the new host. However i noticed that some of the tables haven't been restored properly. I want to know if there is a way in which i can restore those specific tables without overwriting data. (just insert what has been missed). I am a complete newbie in this matter.  I searched for the solution here but couldn't make out anything probably because i have no programming knowledge. Someone please help.

Comment: You're asking for some running code and you don't have any programming knowledge to check what it means. This is very risky. I would overwrite everything if I were you, and forget about the fresh data.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup file of that tables and then restore backup file on new server.

> However i noticed that some of the
>   tables haven't been restored properly.

Does it give any error? How are you restoring this tables?

Comment: actually i have noticed that many "tags" are missing from my WP posts. i checked the restored database and noticed that it wasn't restored properly.

Comment: I checked the logs at mysqldumper. It doesn't show up any errors. And yet i have many tags missing from my posts.

Comment: is it possible to try again restore?

Comment: Well that would result in me losing any fresh data that i have added. I noticed the missing tags error long after i moved to the new host, my bad. That is why i wanted to know if i could just insert the missing data without rewriting the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

you must checks (Select from DB)all specific table which you want to insert export.

then go to new host phpmyadmin panel and import exported table only